# Cause code to be pre-JITted at run time without using PrepareMethod

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, jit

I need to cause some code in my application to be pre-JITted. The scenario is an XNA game running under Windows Phone. When an explosion first happens, there is a noticeable pause while the methods that implement the explosion physical modelling are JITted. I know this because this issue happens on the Windows build as well, and disappears when the assemblies are NGEN'd. I have also used the method of JITting at runtime which is mentioned in a few answers here and [originates on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31316/Pre-compile-pre-JIT-your-assembly-on-the-fly-or-tr) (using reflection and [`PrepareMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.preparemethod.aspx)) .

However, I can't use NGEN, because it's a Windows Phone app. I also can't use the other method `PrepareMethod` is marked as `SecurityCritical`, and you can't call that on Windows Phone.

I don't mind the fact that it may take some time, because the initialisation would happen on a separate thread while a loading screen is displayed.

Are there any elegant methods to achieve a similar result and, failing that, any methods at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone as of now, the only thing you can do is force the method to be JITed is by actually calling it.

I would call the method while your application is loading, perhaps while it is showing a load screen or something. That way when the user actually hits it during the game, the JIT has already been taken care of.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there might be an interesting way of causing JITting with delegates or something like that. Do you know of some further reading on the topic - as my Google-FU has proved weak on this topic...

Comment: @MattWhitfield I've come to this answer entirely by process of elimination. All of the options that are available on the desktop CLR are restricted in WP7. Note that WP8 will allow native code in XNA.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait a couple of days and see if something surprising comes up, but I took this route and it worked out OK. Breaks my heart a bit, making lots of useless calls, but it does improve the performance on the first actual run hugely. I'm interested by you saying 'native code in XNA' - do you mean C++/CX with DirectX, NGEN of a CLR XNA assembly or something else entirely? Thanks again.

Comment: @MattWhitfield It isn't entirely clear yet since the SDK and OS isn't available yet, but Microsoft [has indicated](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/06/20/announcing-windows-phone-8.aspx) that Windows Phone 8 will support C++ and DirectX.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that but just wanted to check I hadn't missed anything major!